# name=Bad_NodeIdUnknown, value=0x80340000, quality=bad (opc ua milo WriteExample about the NodeId)

Tags: java, identifier, opc-ua, milo

I would like to have a test to write "1" into kepware(PLC) address through opc ua milo client. I get the client from GitHub , the URL is https://github.com/eclipse/milo . But I always got inaccurate information, like this:

> [main] INFO  o.e.m.examples.client.WriteExample -
> StatusCode{name=Bad_NodeIdUnknown, value=0x80340000, quality=bad}

Meanwhile, I can successfully read the data from kepware(PLC) .

My opc tagname is "AFSM010_WriteRFID" ,the channalname is "FE6" and the devicename is "AFSM" . So , what's the second parameter of NodeId ? ??

```
public class WriteExample implements ClientExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WriteExample example = new WriteExample();

        new ClientExampleRunner(example).run();
    }

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void run(OpcUaClient client, CompletableFuture<OpcUaClient> future) throws Exception {
        // synchronous connect
        client.connect().get();

//        List<NodeId> nodeIds = ImmutableList.of(new NodeId(2, "HelloWorld/ScalarTypes/Int32"));
//        NodeId nodeId_Tag1 = new NodeId(3, "FE6.AFSM.AFSM010_WriteRFID");
        NodeId nodeId_Tag1 = new NodeId(3, "AFSM010_WriteRFID");
        List<NodeId> nodeIds = ImmutableList.of(nodeId_Tag1);

//        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Variant v = new Variant(5);

            // don't write status or timestamps
            DataValue dv = new DataValue(v, null, null);

            // write asynchronously....
            CompletableFuture<List<StatusCode>> f =
                client.writeValues(nodeIds, ImmutableList.of(dv));

            // ...but block for the results so we write in order
            List<StatusCode> statusCodes = f.get();
            StatusCode status = statusCodes.get(0);

            if (status.isGood()) {
                logger.info("Wrote '{}' to nodeId={}", v, nodeIds.get(0));
            }
        logger.info("this is the end : status " + status.toString());
//        }

        future.complete(client);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you connect to Kepware with a client like UaExpert and browse the address space, find the Node(s) you're interested in, and take a look at how Kepware is formatting the NodeIds.

Every server will have its own "rules" for how it makes NodeIds. You can't derive a NodeId from just knowing the "tag name" without know the rules for that server.

It is expected that you discover Nodes and NodeIds either by browsing or by some out-of-band mechanism where you already know the format.

Comment: Dear Kevin , when i browse the nodes with BrowseNodeExample , i get the node like this : NodeId{ns=2, id=FE6.AFSM.AFSM010_WriteFlag} . 

So , when i would like to write data with WriteExample , i have defined the nodeidlike this :  
NodeId nodeId_Tag1 = new NodeId(3, "FE6.AFSM.AFSM010_WriteRFID") .

I feel confused very much .

Comment: NodeId nodeId_Tag1 = new NodeId(3, "FE6.AFSM.AFSM010_WriteRFID")  .
This way still doesn't work , so why ?

Comment: Why are you writing a NodeId ending with `WriteRFID` when right before that you said it returned one ending with `WriteFlag`? And why did you change the namespace index from 2 to 3?

Comment: Because I have defined the tagname of the PLC module address (e.g:DB28.STRING0)  with 'AFSM010_WriteRFID'  in  kepware .  So sorry,  maybe i have copied the wrong tagname , the right is WriteRFID . The tagname 'AFSM010_WriteRFID' and 'AFSM010_WriteFlag' mean different bussiness  requirements.
 When i use 2 , the application returns Bad_TypeMismatch, like this :StatusCode{name=Bad_TypeMismatch, value=0x80740000, quality=bad} . Then , if  I  changed the parameter to 3 ,  the application returns  Bad_NodeIdUnknown as above.

Comment: Dear Kevin ，i am from NingBo, China,  I am studying  the opc ua  to  read and write data from PLC (through kepware , make kepware as a opc ua server) recently. Do you have WhatsApp or Wechat ?  I want to communicate with you about the opc ua quickly.

Comment: You had the right NodeId when the server returned Bad_TypeMismatch, it just means you supplied a value of the wrong DataType.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have solved the problems . It's the  wrong DataType .